# Does the GameEngine you plan to use need to be written in the same language you are programming the game in?

Tags: language-agnostic

While my common sense says "Yeah. Duh.", I thought I read something somewhere long long ago that referenced the ability to use different programming languages in harmony and wondered if something like that applied here.

IE, if a game engine is written in C++, but the game I'm developing has been written in C#/XNA, can that game engine be utilized for this game?

Comment: No, no xna isn't a game engine. It's a framework.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the language you use to write game engines aims for efficiency and speed. The language you use to write games aims for simplicity and expressiveness. So, it totally makes sense to use a different language for each purpose.

How they will work together is a different story. Usually, the engine's API will be given a convenient interface to be used in the game "scripting" language, so the latter will interact with the engine through successive API calls. The "heavy lifting" will be all done by the engine though...